# Conditional Rending of a Angular Component

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am creating a simple MCQ paper using Ionic and Angular. I am trying to render angular reusable components according to the JSON data file. In my JSON data array, there are three types of mcq questions. Also, I have three reusable components and I need to render them according to the type of the mcq. I have checked the type of the MCQ using for loop but I have no idea how to call to the component from ts file.

This is my JSON data file

```
"questions": [
            [
                {
                    "index": 1,
                    "type": "single-select",
                    "text": "If 5x plus 32 equals 4 minus 2x what is the value of x ?",
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "index": "A",
                            "value": "-4"
                        },
                        {
                            "index": "B",
                            "value": "-3"
                        },
                        {
                            "index": "C",
                            "value": "4"
                        },
                        {
                            "index": "D",
                            "value": "7"
                        },
                        {
                            "index": "E",
                            "value": "12"
                        }
                    ],
                    "correctAnswers": {
                        "indexes": [
                            "A"
                        ]
                    },
                    "points": "10",
                    "time": "30"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "index": 2,
                    "type": "multi-select",
                    "text": "let X * Y = 12. What are the possible values for X and Y ?",
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "index": 1,
                            "value": "X=4 and Y=3",
                            "isChecked": false
                        },
                        {
                            "index": 2,
                            "value": "X=8 and Y=2",
                            "isChecked": false
                        },
                        {
                            "index": 3,
                            "value": "X=6 and Y=2",
                            "isChecked": false
                        },
                        {
                            "index": 4,
                            "value": "X=3 and Y=5",
                            "isChecked": false
                        },
                        {
                            "index": 5,
                            "value": "X=1 and Y=1",
                            " isChecked": false
                        }
                    ],
                    "correctAnswers": {
                        "indexes": [
                            1,
                            3,
                            5
                        ]
                    },
                    "points": "10",
                    "time": "30"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "index": 3,
                    "type": "dropdown-select",
                    "text": "What is the 3rd color of the rainbow ?",
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "index": 1,
                            "value": "Green"
                        },
                        {
                            "index": 2,
                            "value": "Red"
                        },
                        {
                            "index": 3,
                            "value": "Yellow"
                        },
                        {
                            "index": 4,
                            "value": "Pink"
                        },
                        {
                            "index": 5,
                            "value": "Blue"
                        }
                    ],
                    "correctAnswers": {
                        "indexes": [
                            3
                        ]
                    },
                    "points": "10",
                    "time": "30"
                }
            ],
]
```

I have created reusable components using @Input and @Output. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why do you want to achieve this in the ts file? What you can do is to implement the loop in the template and using a switch can can render one of you components.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this functionality by using the component factory resolver to generate components and attach them to some HTML element.

First you will need a directive, which will be used to attach the components

```js
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appRef]',
})
export class RefDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}
```

Inside the component where you want to attach the rest of the components you will use the directive like so

```html
<ng-template appRef></ng-template>
```

And your typescript for the component will look like so

```js
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(RefDirective, { static: true }) ref: RefDirective;
  config = [
    {
      type: 'single',
    },
    {
      type: 'multy',
    },
    {
      type: 'single',
    },
    {
      type: 'dropdown',
    },
  ];

  cmpMap = {
    single: SingleComponent,
    multy: MultyComponent,
    dropdown: DropdownComponent,
  };

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let directiveContainerRef = this.ref.viewContainerRef;
    this.config.forEach((x) => {
      let cmp = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
        this.cmpMap[x.type]
      );
      directiveContainerRef.createComponent(cmp);
    });
  }
}
```

So the thing that we are doing is creating a directive, that has `viewContainerRef` inside its constructor, we will attach this directive to the places where we want to insert our dynamic components.

After that for each component that we want to dynamically insert inside the template, we use the componetFactoryResolver, in order to create it first, and after that, we are attaching it via the `RefDirective`.
Pretty much that is all, you can also pass data to the newly created components if needed, via the reference that is returned from the `viewRef.create`.

Here is a live example : [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zuuxw7?file=src%2Fmulty%2Fmulty.component.html)

Side Notes:

0. You can create a dedicated component instead of a directive, and attach the components to the component itself.
1. If you are using Angular 13, the component factory resolver won't be required.
2. Here is a link to the docs with official example [NG-Docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)
3. The comment by [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11020016/thomas-renger) about implementation that uses ng-switchcase is also legit, and probably is more straightforward